# I need it to convert from an Int to a double

Tags: java, swing, int, double

This is my code that I have so far.

I need to convert the last if statement into a double

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double skill = 0;   double hours = 0;  double overTime= 0.5; int insurance =0;

    String[] choices = {"Medical Insurance", "Dental Insurance", "Long-Term Disability      Insurance"};

        double MedicalInsuranceCount  = 32.50;
        double DentalInsuranceCount  = 20.00;
        double LongTermDisabilityInsuranceCount = 10.00

    if (skill >= 20.00 && skill <=22.00)

    insurance = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
            null                            // Center in window.// prompts the user to select a button
          , "Types of Insurance options"    // Message
          , "Insurance option"              // Title in titlebar
          , JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION       // Option type
          , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE       // messageType
          , null                            // Icon (none)
          , choices                         // Button text as above.
          , "None of your business"         // Default button's label
    );                 

    switch (insurance)

            {
                case 0: 
                    MedicalInsuranceCount++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    DentalInsuranceCount++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    LongTermDisabilityInsuranceCount++;
                    break;
                default:
                    //... If we get here, something is wrong.  Defensive programming.
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unexpected response " + insurance);
            }

// this is where the problem is I think.

    if(insurance == 0)
        insurance = Math.round((float)MedicalInsuranceCount);

    else if(insurance == 1) 
        insurance = Math.round((float)DentalInsuranceCount); 
    else if(insurance == 2) 
        insurance = Math.round((float)LongTermDisabilityInsuranceCount);
    System.out.println(insurance);
    }
}
```

ive tried to use Double.PasreDouble but that failed and Math.round(float) is the only thing that works

Comment: What is it outputting, what were you expecting, and what is wrong with `Math.round(float)` if it works?

Comment: You're using the `insurance` variable for multiple purposes. First you need to sort that out, then we can help you (if that is still necessary)

Comment: Your first if block will **never** run since skill will always be 0 when the if block comes around.

Answer (score 2):

You don't explicitly state what type `insurance` is, but there are *two* different signatures for `Math#round`:

- [`Math.round(double) -> long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double))
- [`Math.round(float) -> int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float))

If your `insurance` variable is declared to be an `int`, you won't be able to assign a `long` into it (incompatible types).

Comment: the switch case needs to be an Int, im trying to set the values of "dental Insurance Count" to insurance so it can become a value to i use later on... is there maybe a different way instead of switch case then?

Comment: Use a different variable for your switch statement.  You don't want to conflate the meaning of it in your program, since that will make it unreadable.

Comment: @TonyConnorMalynn Try to write a short, simple, accurate comment for each variable declaration, saying exactly what the variable means. If you can't do that, reconsider how you are using the variable.

Answer (score 1):

One problem that your code is showing is that you're using the `insurance` variable to do too many things, including holding logical data -- what *type* of insurance are we dealing with, and floating point numeric data -- how much does the insurance cost. Don't do this. Use separate variables for separate functionality.

Also I have a sneaking suspicion that yours is not so much a rounding of a number problem but rather a *display* of formatted number problem. If so, then concentrate less on rounding the number and more on displaying properly formatted output. A NumberFormat type of object can help you with this. For example...

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Foo5 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      double insurance = 32.50;

      NumberFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
      NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

      System.out.println("Insurance is: " + decimalFormat.format(insurance));
      System.out.println("Insurance in dollars is: " + currencyFormat.format(insurance));
   }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Insurance is: 32.50
Insurance in dollars is: $32.50
```